# dataTables: no paging buttons

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use dataTables inside a JIRA gadget and after my table is ready there are no pagination buttons available. I have a table and I'm using the dataTables in a simpliest way: 
$("#mytableid").dataTable();

After browsing elements of my page I can see that the corresponding div's are empty:

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_two_button" id="mytableid_paginate">
    <div class="paginate_disabled_previous" title="Previous" id="mytableid_previous"></div>
    <div class="paginate_enabled_next" title="Next" id="mytableid_next"></div>
</div>
```

I assume that there should be some logic for buttons, etc. Any ideas of why this is happening?

I've tried to switch to "full_numbers", there I can see just a simple text "FirstPrevious123...NextLast" in one row without any button functionality.

I suppose that something isn't going the right way after parsing my table, but I don't know where to search. Any hints?

My table doesn't have  part. And there are no css styles applied. dataTables 1.8.4, jquery 1.6.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think that the problem is that you are not loading datatables css. You should include the file demo_table.css

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing =) Thank you